# How can I have a jQuery hover event re-trigger on overlapping elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I currently a function that fires when triggered by a jQuery hover event. Some elements are added to the DOM via Javascript, others are already in the HTML file. My code is as follows:

```js
$('<a>').attr('href', '#').attr('class', 'icon').css('left', 4).html($('<img>').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/bQFAeqi.png')).appendTo($('body'));

$('body').hover(function(e) {
    var firstClassName = $(e.target)[0].className.split(' ')[0];
    console.log(firstClassName);
  },
  function() {
    console.log('hover out')
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.panel {
  left: 4px;
  top: 34px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #E0D0C8;
  position: absolute;
  border: thick solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.icon {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  top: 4px;
}
.icon img {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel"></div>
</body>
```

The unintended behavior is that when I hover over an element and afterwards hover over another element which is overlapping, the hover event won't re-trigger.

For example, when I hover over the `.icon` which is overlapping the `#text-panel`, the hover event will only re-trigger if the mouse exits both elements and the `hover out` event triggers. How can I make the hover event re-trigger without having the mouse exit all overlapping elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Same event handler for the exact set of elements by using `$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.icon, .panel',function(e)`

```js
$('<a>').attr('href', '#').attr('class', 'icon').css('left', 4).html($('<img>').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/bQFAeqi.png')).appendTo($('body'));

$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.icon, .panel',function(e) {
    var firstClassName = $(e.target)[0].className.split(' ')[0];
    console.log(firstClassName+'-'+e.type);
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.panel {
  left: 4px;
  top: 34px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #E0D0C8;
  position: absolute;
  border: thick solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.icon {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
  top: 4px;
}
.icon img {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  min-width: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="panel"></div>
</body>
```